# Laravel 10 Image upload with Ajax validation error

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, validation

I want upload an Image without form submit using ajax and laravel-10. I have ceated Route Controller and Model and send the file to the laravel controller using an Ajax function. But on validation my upload file (Image) is rejected with "***The image field is required.***"
below is my controller function and Image sending script.

**ProductController.php**

```
public function store_image(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        
        $request->validate([
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
        ]);
          
        $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();  
        $request->image->move(public_path('images/products'), $imageName);
        
        if($request->hasFile($imageName)){ 
            return response()->json([
                'product_image_name' => $imageName,
            ]);
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'product_image_name' => FALSE,
            ]);
        }

    }
```

**Create.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app') @section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('CREATE PRODUCT') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form
                        method="POST"
                        action="{{route('store-product')}}"
                        id="image-form"
                        enctype="multipart/form-data"
                    >
                        @csrf
                        <div
                            class="alert alert-danger print-error-msg"
                            style="display: none"
                        >
                            <ul></ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mb-3">
                            <label
                                for="name"
                                class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end"
                                >{{ __('Title') }}</label
                            >

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input
                                    id="title"
                                    type="text"
                                    name="title"
                                    class="form-control @error('title') is-invalid @enderror"
                                    value="{{ old('title') }}"
                                    required
                                    autocomplete="title"
                                    autofocus
                                />

                                @error('title')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row mb-3">
                            <label
                                for="lot_code"
                                class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end"
                                >{{ __('Description') }}</label
                            >

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <textarea
                                    id="description"
                                    name="description"
                                    rows="5"
                                    cols="10"
                                    class="form-control @error('description') is-invalid @enderror"
                                ></textarea>

                                @error('description')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mb-3">
                            <label
                                for="color_id"
                                class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end"
                                >{{ __('Color') }}</label
                            >

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select
                                    class="form-select form-control @error('color') is-invalid @enderror"
                                    name="color_id"
                                >
                                    <option value="">
                                        {{__('Select Product Color') }}
                                    </option>
                                    @foreach($colors as $color)
                                    <option value="{{$color-">
                                        id}}>{{$color->color}}
                                    </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>

                                @error('color')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mb-3">
                            <label
                                for="lot_code"
                                class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end"
                                >{{ __('Size') }}</label
                            >

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select
                                    class="form-select form-control @error('size') is-invalid @enderror"
                                    name="size_id"
                                >
                                    <option value="">
                                        {{__('Select Product Size') }}
                                    </option>
                                    @foreach($sizes as $size)
                                    <option value="{{$size-">
                                        id}}>{{$size->size}}
                                    </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>

                                @error('size')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mb-3">
                            <label
                                for="lot_code"
                                class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end"
                                >{{ __('Image') }}</label
                            >

                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input
                                    type="file"
                                    name="image"
                                    id="inputImage"
                                    class="form-control form-control-file"
                                />
                                <small
                                    id="imageHelp"
                                    class="form-text text-muted"
                                    >{{ __('Only: jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg.
                                    Max:2048') }}</small
                                >

                                <span
                                    class="invalid-feedback"
                                    id="image-error"
                                    role="alert"
                                >
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <a
                                    href="#"
                                    class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary"
                                    id="image-upload"
                                    >UPLOAD</a
                                >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button
                                    type="submit"
                                    class="btn btn-primary float-end"
                                >
                                    {{ __('CREATE') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 mb-2">
                            <img id="preview-image" width="300px" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    /*------------------------------------------
        --------------------------------------------
        Generating user Preview
        --------------------------------------------
        --------------------------------------------*/
    $("#inputImage").change(function () {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => {
            $("#preview-image").attr("src", e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    });

    $("#image-upload").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var productImage = document.getElementById("inputImage").files[0];

        var productImage = $("#inputImage").prop("files")[0];
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append("image", productImage);

        //console.log(productImage);
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "{{ route('upload-product-image') }}",
            headers: {
                "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content"),
            },
            mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
            data: form_data, //{ 'image': productImage} ,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Image uploaded successfully");
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("Image upload failed");
            },
        });
    });
</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: console log `productImage ` and see it has value on it

Comment: $Abdulla Bilam Console value is : File {name: 'excecutive-blooms.png', lastModified: 1521274330590, lastModifiedDate: Sat Mar 17 2018 13:42:10 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 133463, …}

Comment: But controller gives me message " The image field is required"

Comment: Check  https://makitweb.com/how-to-upload-a-file-using-jquery-ajax-in-laravel/

Comment: (Unrelated) None of your label's `for` attributes points to a relevant `id` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#attributes

Comment: add ``contentType:false`` in your ajax and try it.

Comment: Didn't Help. But I can see Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Gordon-Robertson.png"
Content-Type: image/png

Answer (score 0):

add

```
contentType: false
```

in the $.ajax function